# First order linear differential equations 3

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am not sure how to set up the equation for this question or what steps i should be taking. Please help!

[image]

Comment: The answer is B

Answer (score 0):

[rate in]$=24 g/min$ [rate out]$=4(S/68)$ (four galons per minute leaked from the tank that has an amount of salt of $S/68$ As said in the wording of the problem,

$S'=$[rate in]-[rate out], $S'=24-S/17$. The solution is B as Noah said.

The solution is $S(t)=408-408e^{-t/17}$